# Shutdown OS with NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm, osdev, 16-bit

I have been writing a `16-bit Operating System` and I would like the user to be able to shut down the computer without actually hitting the power button. Is there a way in `Assembly` for me to shutdown the computer?

Comment: Why are you going to limit yourself to only an Assembly language solution?  Why are you asking a programming question on Superuser?

Answer (score -1):

```
mov ax, 0x1000
mov ax, ss
mov sp, 0xf000
mov ax, 0x5307
mov bx, 0x0001
mov cx, 0x0003
int 0x15
```

Comment: Please explain why this works.

Comment: It work on VMs, i tried it on QEMU and Virtual Box, but it wont work well on real hardware. This code is from debian wheezy with standard packages.

Comment: This copies the error we already saw in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57596048/how-can-i-make-the-os-wait-a-second-before-shutdown-nasm/ (or was it copied *to* that question?), `mov ax, ss` should be `mov ss, ax`. Can you point us to the exact source?