# How can i make the os wait a second before shutdown ( nasm )

Tags: x86, operating-system, kernel, nasm, x86-16

```
powerCommand:
    mov si, powerOFF
    call printString
    ;sleep command here
    mov ax, 0x1000
    mov ax, ss
    mov sp, 0xf000
    mov ax, 0x5307
    mov bx, 0x0001
    mov cx, 0x0003
    int 0x15
    ret
```

I want the program wait for 1 second then continue with shutdown. At the moment it shuts down instantly after the shutdown message. I am running it on my custom os made in nasm.

Comment: This is 16 bit code, you've got the BIOS hanging around still, right?

Comment: yes i do have the bios

Comment: `mov ax, 0x1000` `mov ax, ss` The second instruction is most probably wrong! `mov ax, 0x1000` `mov  ss, ax` will work better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your program is loaded by the ROM-BIOS (not EFI), and you're running in (Real/Virtual) 86 Mode, and you have interrupts enabled (`sti`), and you didn't reconfigure the PIC and the PIT, and also didn't change the interrupt 8 (default IRQ 0) handler, then you can use the dword at 0_046Ch (equivalently, 40h:6Ch) which holds the timer ticks since midnight, and is incremented circa 18.2 times per second (at circa 18.2 Hz) by the ROM-BIOS's interrupt 8 handler.

In my programs I generally just check for how often the lower word of the counter changes, which will usually be accurate enough, and doesn't need any special midnight rollover handling.

(The naive approach is to take the current tick count and add however many ticks you want to wait, then when looping check whether the tick dword is above-or-equal the calculated value. However, this requires midnight rollover handling to correctly work in all circumstances.)

Here's the source part for some timer handling in a project of mine: https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/82570f7094b8/source/debug.asm#l1367

```
.timer:
    push ax
    push dx
    push cx
    push es

    mov dx, 40h
    mov es, dx

    mov cx, word [getline_timer_count]
    mov dx, word [getline_timer_last]

    cmp dx, word [es:6Ch]
    je .timer_next
    mov dx, word [es:6Ch]
    inc cx
    mov al, 18
    mul byte [serial_keep_timeout]
    test ax, ax
    jz .timer_next
    cmp cx, ax
    jb .timer_next

    pop es
    mov dx, msg.serial_no_keep_timer
    jmp .no_keep

.timer_next:
    mov word [getline_timer_count], cx
    mov word [getline_timer_last], dx
    pop es
    pop cx
    pop dx
    pop ax
    retn
```

Here's the setup of that timer:

```
    xor ax, ax
    mov word [getline_timer_count], ax
    mov word [getline_timer_last], ax
    mov word [getline_timer_func], .timer

    call getline00
```

getline00 repeatedly calls the function pointer in `word [getline_timer_func]` while waiting for input, if input is done from the serial port (which is the case whenever we use this timer). That's at https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/82570f7094b8/source/lineio.asm#l814 :

```
    call near word [getline_timer_func]
```

And the following line disables the timer by pointing at an empty function (that's just a single `retn`):

```
    mov word [getline_timer_func], dmycmd
```

---

Putting it all together, here's your sleep handler:

```
%assign SLEEP_SECONDS 1

sleep:
        xor cx, cx      ; initialise counter to zero
        xor dx, dx      ; initialise "prior value" to zero
                        ; (any value will do, at worst it is a match to the
                        ;  tick low word and we will wait one tick longer)

        mov ax, 40h
        mov es, ax      ; => ROM-BIOS data area
.loop:
        cmp word [es:6Ch], dx
                        ; still same ?
        je .next        ; yes, just wait for next -->
        mov dx, word [es:6Ch]
                        ; update our last-seen low tick word value
        inc cx          ; increment our counter
        cmp cx, SLEEP_SECONDS * 18
                        ; as many ticks elapsed as we want ?
        jae .end        ; yes, end the loop -->

                        ; (fall through to .next)
.next:
        sti             ; insure interrupts are enabled for the hlt
        hlt             ; idle the machine while waiting for IRQs

        jmp .loop       ; continue the loop -->


.end:
```

Changes from my program's source:

- The *sleep* tick timeout is calculated at assembling time from a preprocessor define for the seconds, instead of using a variable at run time.
- The counter and last seen value are not stored in variables between the iterations, rather they are always kept in `cx` and `dx`.
- The function pointer framing is not used, as the pointer would be a constant during the sleep handling.
- Instead of returning from the timer function until it is called again, we just jump back to the `.loop` local label. This also means we do not have to preserve the register contents with `push` and `pop`.
- Instead of checking for a keypress (which in my program eventually idles the machine too), we just sit in a tight loop here. The `hlt` makes it so that the machine can idle.

Comment: I'm the upvote, however it might be worth mentioning that if you are on an AT (286) or later there is the BIOS function [Int 15h/AH=86h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1525.htm) that can be used as a wait.

Comment: https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/metakern/file/a5625f7c0b14/source/metakern/metakern.asm#l301 This is an example of a naive timer. It uses only the lower 16 bits but checks for `cx` > `word [40h:6Ch]` to keep looping. If the calculation of `cx` overflows, the timer returns prematurely. If `cx` is calculated just before midnight, the timer may run for too long.